# Изменение ImageSource без создания нового экземпляра

Tags: c#, wpf

Возможно ли в Wpf присвоить значение ImageSource однажды, а затем изменять его без создания нового экземпляра класса. 
Предположим есть изображение 500х500 пикселей, и необходимо его обновить, но не полностью, а лишь часть (пусть будет 200x200), насколько я понимаю быстрее обновить только ту часть изображения, которая изменилась, но я не нашел такой возможности в .net/wpf.
Изначально я думал, что так можно сделать через WritableBitmap, однако после `Freeze`, его нельзя снова сделать доступным для изменения.

P.S. Насколько знаю, так работает вывод с видеокарты на низком уровне (так называемые `DirtyRectangles`, в которых производится обновление только необходимой части экрана)

Comment: Берите ObservableCollection, и заменяйте значение на новое и все, зачем такие трудности?

Comment: @Gardes, если это маленькое изображения, то и вправду смысла не имеет, а если у меня выводится огромное изображение, а обновить необходимо только малую часть, то получается очень неэффективно и по памяти, и по процессору делать такую задачу, намного проще обновить именно ту малую часть

Comment: Я наверное не в тему, но я бы посоветовал рассмотреть другой вариант - выводить не одно большое изображение, а кучу небольших тайлов и обновлять только нужные тайлы. Это, конечно, не суперэффективно, но лучше, чем обновлять большое изображение целиком.

Comment: @tym32167, полностью согласен, только тогда мы упираемся в то, что при необходимости обновить все изображение, мы должны отрендерить все изображение, разбить на n частей, а потом из каждой части создать новый экземпляр ImageSource, присвоить и офигеть от того как все это будет медленно работать )), однако если изначально изображение можно представить в виде тайлов и обновляться будет по-тайлово, тогда такой вариант более чем хорош.
З.Ы. карты или типо того

Answer (score 1):

Для таких целей предназначен [WriteableBitmap](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/graphics_and_animation/level14/14_5.php).

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
```

код обновления:

```
public WriteableBitmap Image { get; set; }

public MainVM()
{
    Image = new WriteableBitmap(100, 100, 300, 300, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
}

void updateImageExecute()
{  
    byte blue = 0;
    byte green = 00;
    byte red = 95;
    byte alpha = 255;
    byte[] colorData = { blue, green, red, alpha };

    for (int x = 0; x < 35; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 35; y++)
        {
            Int32Rect rect = new Int32Rect(x, y, 1, 1);
            int stride = (Image.PixelWidth * Image.Format.BitsPerPixel) / 8;

                Image.WritePixels(rect, colorData, stride, 0);
        }
    }            
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тогда, возникает вопрос зачем нужен метод `Freeze`, просто я столкнулся с проблемой, что без freeze не выводилось изображение, но после freeze я не мог менять изображение

Comment: алсо, WritePixels, очень медленный, а у Вас еще `rect` 1х1 и меняется в цикле, проще уж один раз var rect = new Int32Rect(0,0,35,35), но тем не менее спасибо

Comment: как я понял это метод позволяет записывать только 1 пиксель)

Comment: есть метод `WritePixels` он записывает внутри прямоугольника, а есть `SetPixel`, он один пиксель

Comment: да и для моей задачи мне необходимо не просто цветом заполнять, а отрисовывать картинку, причем довольно быстро, поэтому я использую `Marshal.Copy(frame.Bytes, offset, CurrentBitmap.BackBuffer, frame.Bytes.Length);`, но изображение не обновляется

Comment: так можно картинку перевести в массив байтов, и закинуть в метод

Comment: ага,так и делаю, только не обновляется картинка)

Comment: Таки решение нашел, `AddDirtyRect` указывает где обновлять изображение

Comment: @max619, отлично)